What is the unicode braces {| |} (⦃ ... ⦄) in lean 4?
I came across the use of a Unicode braces here ⦃ ... ⦄

In Lean the definition looks like this:
def Set.Subset (U V : Set α) : Prop := ∀ ⦃x⦄, x ∈ U → x ∈ V

I am not sure what it is exactly. I know that for quantified variables, there is
(x : ℕ) or {x : ℕ}, as in:
example : ∀ (x: ℕ), x ≥ 0 := by sorry
example : ∀ {x: ℕ}, x ≥ 0 := by sorry

How is ∀ ⦃x⦄ different from the above, and why do we need this new notation?

It should be noted that the plain ASCII version of ⦃x⦄ is {{x}}. I personally think the latter makes even more sense: "optionally optional".

They are called strict implicit binders.  The only place I can find them officially documented is in the code itself:

The difference between implicit {} and strict-implicit ⦃⦄ is how
implicit arguments are treated that are not followed by explicit arguments.
{} arguments are applied eagerly, while ⦃⦄ arguments are left partially applied:
def foo {x : Nat} : Nat := x
def bar ⦃x : Nat⦄ : Nat := x
#check foo -- foo : Nat
#check bar -- bar : ⦃x : Nat⦄ → Nat


You can also find more discussion on strict implicits on these two Zulip topics:

Need help to understand strict implicit vs implicit
What do these double curly braces ⦃⦄ mean?


⦃x: X⦄ are arguments that are implicit like {x: X}, but only if some arguments to their right are given.
So for example in the case of Set.Subset with just one argument, say you have:

h: Subset A B, meaning h: ∀ ⦃c⦄, c ∈ A → c ∈ B, and
hc: c ∈ A,

then c is an implicit argument of h, meaning:

h hc : c ∈ B, with c implicit from hc
h c hc – type mismatch (tries to match c to the hypothesis left of →).

but the difference is that h without arguments can be used where the whole ∀ ... is expected:

say you have foo: (∀ a, a ∈ A → a ∈ B) → Whatever
foo h : Whatever – OK.

If Subset had used single-bracket ∀ {c}, ... instead, then you would have to write foo @h instead. Of course here it's hardly a problem, this matters more when you have many arguments.
They're documented in the section "More on implicit arguments" of Theorem Proving in Lean 4, with more examples of how and why one would use them.

Just in case, a full MWE:
import Mathlib.Data.Set.Basic

variable {A: Set α} {B: Set α}
variable {c: α} {hc: c ∈ A}

def SubsetX (s₁ s₂ : Set α) :=
  ∀ a, a ∈ s₁ → a ∈ s₂

def SubsetY (s₁ s₂ : Set α) :=
  ∀ {a}, a ∈ s₁ → a ∈ s₂

def SubsetZ (s₁ s₂ : Set α) :=
  ∀ ⦃a⦄, a ∈ s₁ → a ∈ s₂

variable (hx: SubsetX A B)
variable (hy: SubsetY A B)
variable (hz: SubsetZ A B)

#check hx -- SubsetX A B
#check hy -- ?m.1 ∈ A → ?m.1 ∈ B
#check hz -- SubsetZ A B

#check hz hc -- c ∈ B

variable (foo: (∀ a, a ∈ A → a ∈ B) → False)
#check foo hx  -- OK
#check foo hy  -- type mismatch
#check foo @hy -- OK
#check foo hz  -- OK
#check foo @hz -- OK


#check hx c hc  -- c ∈ B
#check hx hc    -- type mismatch, c not given
#check hy hc    -- c ∈ B
#check hy c hc  -- type mismatch, c should be implicit
#check @hy c hc -- c ∈ B
#check hz hc    -- c ∈ B
#check hz c     -- type mismatch, c interpreted as hc above.

